# website blocks document.getElementById javascript injection

Tags: javascript, bots, javascript-injection

I am looking at this website in particular www.nadex.com
When you log into their platform you can see that the ID of the place order button is "ticket5_orderTicketButton" but when I use that ID to simulate a click it returns that the ID is not on that page. I have tried this with several different IDs and they all do this.

This is the only website I have ever encountered that does this and I am wondering how do they do this, but more importantly how can I still simulate the button click with JavaScript?

Thank you, and I attached a picture below to show what I mean.

[ticket5_orderTicketButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfT4P.png)

Comment: They may have overwritten the function like so `document.getElementById = null`

Comment: Probably it's inside an iframe.

Comment: I dont see any iframes

Comment: @patchariadog `</html>` should be at the bottom, but I see another `</html>` below, and the scrollbar shows there is much more. I'm sure it's a frame.

Comment: Thanks Oriol this was the solution. Did you want to officially answer the question for the credit?